# Adding data to an NSDictionary... SRSLY? Isn't there a quicker way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nsnumber, verbose

I'm from a Flash ActionScript background. Where I'm from, I can set a dictionary-like object like this:

```
var data:Object = {startPoint:5, endPoint:12};
```

So coming to Objective-C, I was surprised to discover that the equivalent to this appears to be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"startPoint"];
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12] forKey:@"endPoint"];
```

Surely there's an easier way... Or is that really my lot?

Comment: Why surprised? Not all languages are the same.

Comment: But some languages are more verbose than others. ;)

I could actually create a value object out of an extended NSObject, and define properties on it... That would make the syntax a lot shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only shorter way I can think of:

```
NSMutableDictionary *petalData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"startPoint", [NSNumber numberWithInt:12], @"endPoint", nil];
```

Comment: True, although because it's so verbose I separated it onto different lines to make it more readable.